# if char equals a letter then execute a code

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, char

Please help I cannot run this block of code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Methods_in_java {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean gameover = true;
        int score = 5000;
        int Levelcomplete = 5;
        int bonus = 100;
        boolean prize = true;
        System.out.println("Please enter your name");
        Scanner lic = new Scanner(System.in);
        String ab = lic.nextLine();
        char fir = Character.toUpperCase(ab.charAt(1));
        if(fir == 'A'){
                prize = true;
        }
        Calculatescore(gameover,score,Levelcomplete,bonus,prize);
    }
    public static void Calculatescore(boolean gameover,int score,int levelcomplete,int bonus,boolean prize){
        if(gameover){
            int finalscore = score + (levelcomplete * bonus);
            if (prize){
                finalscore += 1000;
            }
            System.out.println("Your final score is "+ finalscore);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I cannot run this block of code" Why?

Comment: Which one? `Calculatescore` or the whole main?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please explain why you "cannot run" your code : do you have a compilation error ? a runtime error ? Is the output not what you expected ? along with the relevant messages, description of what you want to achieve, and concrete examples with data and desired result.

Comment: add your error statement if any.

Comment: I am sorry for bad english I mean I cannot get desired outcome the prize always equals true or false depending upon first value i set

Comment: it will get only true and false if its boolean, no surprise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

charAt is zero based.
You should use ab.charAt(0) if you use only a single char.

Another good advice is to start method names with a lower case and use the camelCase format.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer but still it always equals true and output is same

Comment: That's because you initialized prize (which should be 'price' to true). Initialize it as false and it will do what you want :)

Comment: Thankyou so much I am new here so I dont relly know how to ask questions sorry but thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
String ab = lic.nextLine();
char fir = Character.toUpperCase(ab.charAt(1));
```

Is `fir` supposed to be the first character in the user String? In that case you want to make sure to take zero-based indexing into account:

```
char fir = Character.toUpperCase(ab.charAt(0));
```

Comment: thank you so much for the answer but still it always equals true and output is same

Answer (score 0):

You have initialized your **prize** variable as **true** that will remain always **true** even its meet if condition or not just change it to **false**.

and as you were accessing the String's 2nd character using `charAt(1)`, the **index starts from 0** and if you try using `charAt(0)` then you will access 1st character.

Just change your code to:

```
public class cn {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean gameover = true;
        int score = 5000;
        int Levelcomplete = 5;
        int bonus = 100;
        boolean prize=false;
        System.out.println("Please enter your name");
        Scanner lic = new Scanner(System.in);
        String ab = lic.nextLine();
        char fir = Character.toUpperCase(ab.charAt(0));
        if(fir == 'A'){
                prize = true;
        }
        Calculatescore(gameover,score,Levelcomplete,bonus,prize);
    }
    public static void Calculatescore(boolean gameover,int score,int levelcomplete,int bonus,boolean prize){
        if(gameover){
            int finalscore = score + (levelcomplete * bonus);
            if (prize){
                finalscore += 1000;
            }
            System.out.println("Your final score is "+ finalscore);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome @AdityaRajTiwari if you think my post was helpful than you can accept my answer or any other if you found other one better

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you elaborated more on what your problem is, 
do you have a run time error, a compile time error, or it the output just not what you'd expect.
Your problem may be that arrays start at 0 so the first letter is charAt(0).

Actually I believe another user mentioned that the prize variable was initialized to true.  I believe that that is the issue and that answer should be marked correct.

Comment: thank you Czarking sorry for bad english and explanation the real problem was not getting desired output which was supposed to add 1000 only if prize was true but it always adds 1000

Comment: What are some examples of your inputs? add them to your question